# scope strangeness in python class attributes

Tags: python, scope, python-class

Came across what seems to be a weird case of 'spooky action at a distance' using python class attributes.

If I define X as:

```
class X():
    a = list()
    b = int
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.a.append(value)
        self.b = value
```

Then instantiate:

```
u = X(0)
v = X(1)
```

It outputs the following strangeness:

```
u.a == [0,1]
u.b == 0  
v.a == [0,1]
v.b == 1
```

As if the list() from "a" is acting as a shared class attribute while the int from "b" only as an instance attribute. I mean, why would types affect the scope of an attribute ? what am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference isn't the type, it's the way you're rebinding the attributes (or not).

```
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.a.append(value)
        self.b = value
```

In this code, `self.a` is not being rebound; the object it references is being mutated.  Hence `self.a` remains a reference to the (shared) class attribute, `X.a`.

`self.b` is being rebound, and so a new instance attribute is created that shadows the class attribute `X.b`.  Note that `X.b` is the `int` *type*, not an actual int!

```
>>> X.b
<class 'int'>
>>> u.b
0
>>> v.b
1
```

The `id` function can be used to verify that there is only a single `X.a` object:

```
>>> id(X.a)
2052257864960
>>> id(u.a)
2052257864960
>>> id(v.a)
2052257864960
```

whereas obviously the `id`s for the `b` attributes are all different:

```
>>> id(X.b)
140711576840944
>>> id(u.b)
2052256170192
>>> id(v.b)
2052256170224
```

If you wanted a class that mutates its class attributes every time a new instance is created (note: this is kind of a weird thing to do), you can do that by making sure you're modifying the `type` of `self` rather than the `self` instance:

```
class X():
    # Initializing a and b with literal list and int values.
    # This is more idiomatic than doing stuff like list() and int().
    a = []
    b = 0
    def __init__(self, value):
        # Using type(self) as a way to reference X (or a subclass) explicitly.
        # As discussed, this isn't necessary when we're doing self.a.append,
        # but using type() consistently makes it obvious that we're
        # dealing with class attributes, not instance attributes.
        type(self).a.append(value)
        type(self).b = value
```

Trying it out:

```
>>> X(0)
<__main__.X object at 0x000001DDD416AE90>
>>> X(1)
<__main__.X object at 0x000001DDD416B970>
>>> X.b
1
>>> X.a
[0, 1]
```

Comment: Ha, that's a very interesting and instructive answer , thanks ! So if I understand well, in order to unmute a it has to be declared within __init__ right ?

Comment: Depends.  What do you mean by "unmute"?  If you want an attribute to be an instance attribute, you should sent it within `__init__`, and *only* within `__init__`.  Declaring it as a class attribute first and then shadowing it later is just confusing IMO.

Comment: Yep. I was using "unmute" loosely, meaning instance attribute. Up until a few minutes ago I was misunderstanding how class attributes are defined. Pieces are starting to fall in place.

Comment: @tikitakitok it doesn't matter where it happens, `__init__` is just an example. This always applies, even outside of a class or method definition.